# Pandas Group by 2 columns using another column to find the delta

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that has 4909144 rows, with `time` as the index, `source_name`, `dest_address`, and `tvalue` which is just the same as the `time` index.  I have sorted the df by `source_name`, `dest_address`, and `tvalue` using the following so that they are grouped then in order by time:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['sourcehostname','destinationaddress','tvalue'])
```

Which gives me:

```
                        source_name  dest_address   tvalue                 
time                
2019-02-06 15:00:54.000 source_1     72.21.215.90   2019-02-06 15:00:54.000 
2019-02-06 15:01:00.000 source_1     72.21.215.90   2019-02-06 15:01:00.000 
2019-02-06 15:30:51.000 source_1     72.21.215.90   2019-02-06 15:30:51.000 
2019-02-06 15:30:51.000 source_1     72.21.215.90   2019-02-06 15:30:51.000 
2019-02-06 15:00:54.000 source_1     131.107.0.89   2019-02-06 15:00:54.000 
2019-02-06 15:01:14.000 source_1     131.107.0.89   2019-02-06 15:01:14.000 
2019-02-06 15:03:02.000 source_2     69.63.191.1    2019-02-06 15:03:02.000 
2019-02-06 15:08:02.000 source_2     69.63.191.1    2019-02-06 15:08:02.000
```

I want the difference between the times so I then use:

```
#Create delta
df['delta'] = (df['tvalue']-df['tvalue'].shift()).fillna(0)
```

Which gives me:

```
                        source_name  dest_address   tvalue                 delta
time                
2019-02-06 15:00:54.000 source_1     72.21.215.90   2019-02-06 15:00:54.000 00:00:00
2019-02-06 15:01:00.000 source_1     72.21.215.90   2019-02-06 15:01:00.000 00:00:06
2019-02-06 15:30:51.000 source_1     72.21.215.90   2019-02-06 15:30:51.000 00:29:51
2019-02-06 15:30:51.000 source_1     72.21.215.90   2019-02-06 15:30:51.000 00:00:00
2019-02-06 15:00:54.000 source_1     131.107.0.89   2019-02-06 15:00:54.000 -1 days +23:30:03
2019-02-06 15:01:14.000 source_1     131.107.0.89   2019-02-06 15:01:14.000 00:00:20
2019-02-06 15:03:02.000 source_2     69.63.191.1    2019-02-06 15:03:02.000 00:01:48
2019-02-06 15:08:02.000 source_2     69.63.191.1    2019-02-06 15:08:02.000 00:05:00
```

But I would like to group by the `source_name` and `dest_address` and get the difference in the `tvalue` so that I don't run into a  `delta` like `-1 days +23:30:00` or a `delta` like `00:01:48` after the first `source_2` entry when it should be `00:00:00`.

I am trying:

```
df.groupby(['sourcehostname','destinationaddress'])['tvalue'].diff().fillna(0)
```

But this is taking a very very long time and may not provide me with the results I am looking for.

The following doesnt work but can you do something like my original code but add a group by?:

```
#Create delta
df['delta'] = df.groupby(['sourcehostname','destinationaddress'])(df['tvalue']-df['tvalue'].shift()).fillna(0)
```

Comment: I think the first method you suggested is already a good solution, which would be mine as well, but I can imagine the processing can be slow with calculating timedelta's.

Could you try the following:
`df['tvalue2'] = df['tvalue'].astype('int64')//1e9` And after that:

`df.groupby(['sourcehostname','destinationaddress'])['tvalue2'].diff().fillna(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt

source_changed = df['sourcehostname'] != df['sourcehostname'].shift()
dest_changed = df['destinationaddress'] != df['destinationaddress'].shift()
change_occurred = (source_changed | dest_changed)

time_diff = df['tvalue'].diff()

now = dt.datetime.utcnow()
zero_delta = now - now

df['time_diff'] = time_diff
df['change_occurred'] = change_occurred

# Then do a function
# If df['change_occurred'] is True -> set the value of df['delta'] to zero_delta  
# Else set df['delta'] to the value at df['time_dff']
```

Comment: Excellent answer @kudeh I added df.loc[df['change_occurred'] == True, 'time_diff'] = '00:00:00'
 to the end and have my desired output.